# Extract and replace string with bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have a string like: `func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {`

From this, I would like to 1). extract just `showFetchNextSliceFailed` 2). Insert it right above the given line, as `#Mark showFetchNextSliceFailed`.

```
  func showProductsList(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }

  func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }
```

Expected output:

```
  #Mark showProductsList
  func showProductsList(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }

  #Mark showFetchNextSliceFailed
  func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }
```

I tried with grep and sed, but still can't figure out correctly how to extract and replace strings.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382726/extract-and-replace-string-with-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`

- copy the matching pattern space to hold space
- modify the pattern space
- recover the original from hold space and append it

Ex.

```
$ sed '/func show/ {h; s/func \(show[^(]*\).*/#Mark \1/; G;}' file
  #Mark showProductsList
  func showProductsList(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }

  #Mark showFetchNextSliceFailed
  func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following `code` file:

**INPUT:**

```
  $more code
  func showProductsList(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }

  func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }
```

**COMMAND:**

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s/^^( *|\t*)func\s(\w+)func\s(\w+)/\1#Mark \2\n\1func \2/g" code
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  #Mark showProductsList
  func showProductsList(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }

  #Mark showFetchNextSliceFailed
  func showFetchNextSliceFailed(result: UserResult<[Product]>) {

  }
```

EXPLANATIONS:

- `-i.bak` in-place mode for `perl` with backup of the input file
- `s/^( *|\t*)func\s(\w+)func\s(\w+)/\1#Mark \2\n\1func \2/g` find and replace mode detailed at [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rV1zPs/1)